# Guidance on creating a widget

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I would like to display some values into a widget in a similar way as the mechanical counters in a power meter. I have so far only  written a function to split the total value into a single digit corresponding to the required position, it looks something like this:

```
    unsigned long value; // variable holding the value to be displayed

    ....... get the actual value

    int firstPosition  = value % 10;             // 0-9 
    int secondPosition = int(value*0.1) % 10;    // 0 - 9 * 10
    int thirdPosition  = int(value*0.01) % 10;   // 0 - 9 * 100
    int fourthPosition = int(value*0.001) % 10;  // 0 - 9 * 1000
    int fifthPosition  = int(value*0.0001) % 10; // 0 - 9 * 10000
```

Now the actual question, how can I perform the actual animation in order to get a similar behaviour as in a physical device? Has anybody done something similar?

Please note that I am using Qt libraries, just in case it makes a difference.

Cheers.

Comment: You can draw in the `QWidget::paintEvent()`; most tutorials on making a custom widget should explain this. Also check Qwt, they may have the thing you are looking for. http://qwt.sourceforge.net/controlscreenshots.html

Comment: @koan I have already written some widgets overriding QWidget::QPaintEvent() i have also checked for Qwt, They haven't got anything similar to what I am looking for. Cheers.

Comment: OK, so drawing in the paintEvent is insufficient for your needs ? In what way ?

Comment: @koan I apologize, I wasn't clear enough with my question. i am not saying that it is insufficient for my needs, only that I don't know how to do it... So, before trying to reinvent the wheel I might as well look for something that suit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

See the analog clock tutorial at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/widgets-analogclock.html

A one second timer is used to animate the clock, by calling `update()`.

During the `paintEvent()` the widget is drawn for the current time.